# How to make a table row jump in?

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a webpage which is going to contain a list of weekly transactions.

The way I want it to work is to have a list of transaction and when you click it, more detailed information for that week will be presented just below it.

I want it to be presented like a table, but I want the detailed information to jump in like this:
[image]

So when I click the third row the detailed information is shown like this. The specific problem I have is to make the detailed rows jump in.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many different ways to approach this.  One might be to use something like jqGrid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/) or any other number of tabular data presentation components to render the UI.  Essentially what you're talking about is nesting a table within the row of another table and showing/hiding (or dynamically building/destroying) that nested table.

Comment: If you want it to appear on click, you'll need JavaScript (ideally jQuery). If you can live with hover, it can be done with CSS alone. Look to common dropdown menu examples for that.

Comment: If you included a box on the left with + and - icons (plus when collapsed - when expanded).  You can style a checkbox with that + and - icon, and expand your structure with nothing but CSS and the checkbox.  jquery is probably way easier than a pure CSS solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use other table inside of a TD with Colspan, of the TR down.
You can use CSS to create the border.

For example:

```
<table style="border:1px solid #000; border-collapse:collapse;">
    ..
    <tr>
            <Td>Info 2 1 </Td>
            <Td>Info 2 2 </Td>
            <Td>Info 2 3 </Td>
            <Td>Info 2 4 </Td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td  style="border:0px solid #FFF;">
                 <table style="border:0 0 0 50px; border:1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse;">
                     <tr>
                          <td>Detail title 1</td>
                          <td>Detail title 2</td>
                          <td>Detail title 3</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Info 2 1 </td>
            <td>Info 2 2 </td>
            <td>Info 2 3 </td>
            <td>Info 2 4 </td>
    </tr>
    ..
<table>
```

To create dynamically this internal table, you can use the comand "After" of Jquery. 
For example:

```
$('#TR_Selected').after('<tr><td colspan="4"><table> ...</table></td></tr>');
```

Comment: This would work for his HTML structure.  It would require jQuery for the hide/collapse function.

Comment: To create dynamically this internal table, you can use the comand "After" of Jquery. 
For example:

$('#TR_Selected').after('<tr><td colspan="4"><table>...');

Comment: yes, this would work very well. Have the JQuery ready for it, just design issues :p Thanks alot.